# Angular 12 and ngx Boostrap

Tags: angular, ivy, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using Angular 12 and ngx boostrap. i try to build and i have this error :
**This likely means that the library (ngx-bootstrap/modal) which declares BsModalService has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.**

There is any solution ?
Maybe problem is IVY , can i disabled IVY in Angular 12 ?

Answer (score 1):

ivy compiler is enabled by default since `ngx-bootstrap@5.1.0`, check release notes for version `6.0.0` [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/CHANGELOG.md#600-2020-07-10). Try to install the latest version (`8.0.0`) since they support compatibility for angular 12, check [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/CHANGELOG.md#800-2022-01-14).

**Note:** You can disable the ivy compiler by adding the option to your tsconfig:

```
{
...
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
   ...
   "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

Although, I wouldn't recommend the above option, since Angular 9 ivy compiler is used as the default compiler for all new projects.